# iOS - UIWebView not displaying HTML

Tags: html, ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I have a UIViewController inside of which I put a UIWebView

Then I added this to the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BuildBusinessController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *theWebView;

@end
```

and have this as the .m file

```
#import "BuildBusinessController.h"

@interface BuildBusinessController ()

@end

@implementation BuildBusinessController
@synthesize theWebView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    theWebView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTheWebView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"build_business" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
    NSURLRequest *rq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theWebView loadRequest:rq];
}

@end
```

But the build_business.html file is not rendering inside the view, and also I get a warning on this line:  theWebView.delegate = self; which says:

Assigning to id 'UIWebViewDelegate from incompatible type BuildBusinessController *const_string

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong here? It feels I am forgetting some one small thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to F.X. answer, I think you forgot to add this in viewDidAppear (after loadRequest):

```
[self.view addSubview:theWebView];
```

**Update**: The issue is caused by OP failing to configure delegate for UIWebView in Storyboard. The code snippet provided here will only work if you are coding it manually. Otherwise, as stated by @F.X. in the comments below, Storyboard will implement this automatically.

Comment: sorry, where exactly should that line be? I am not noticing the loadRequest - you mean as the last line in viewDidAppear - that didn't work.

Comment: Just to check, did you create the web view using storyboard?

Comment: yes I created the view using the storyboard, but I wrote the code manually, which might be the problem.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to align the windows of xcode so I can drag the arrow from the storyboard to the .h file

Comment: @AlanYeo: There's no need for that, the Storyboard automatically creates and adds the view :)

Comment: @F.X. You are right. I wasn't sure whether he did it using Storyboard initially. But it turns out that he used Storyboard and coded it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You're just forgetting `UIWebViewDelegate` on your class definition :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BuildBusinessController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *theWebView;

@end
```

Comment: although I just tried it and it still didn't fully work :( although it did get rid of the error

Comment: Could the problem be that I use an underscore in my html file build_business ?

Comment: I don't think so. Have you verified that the outlet is set? I also suppose the UIWebView object isn't `null`... Have you tried looking directly inside the bundle in the Simulator to see if the HTML files are actually there?

Comment: I did not add that html file specifically to the bundle - should I do that?

Comment: Yes. You should do that. But just to make sure you have everything setup, you should test this out by doing (instead of using a file):
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];

Comment: I am having a strang thing happen - when i try to add that html file to bundle, it keeps adding an identical html file right in the file system - anyone know why that might happen?

Comment: I believe you checked the box - "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" when adding the file in the dialog box.

Comment: @AlanYeo I tested it with the stackoverflow.com thing and it didnt render.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add "http://". It should be: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17622/discussion-between-geekedout-and-alan-yeo)